# InputStream interference in a Two-way file transfer through sockets

Tags: java, sockets, client, inputstream, outputstream

After editing my code with y'all suggestions, as well as condensing the code to where i can pinpoint the line of code that is causing the problem. 
Server code:`

public class Server2 {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    ServerSocket servsock = null;
    Socket sock = null;
    int SOCKET_PORT = 12362;

    InputStream is = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;

    OutputStream os = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    String FILE_TO_SEND = "SFileToBeSent.txt";
    String FILE_TO_RECEIVED = "CFileReceived.txt";
    int FILE_SIZE = 6022386;

    try {

        System.out.println("Server created.");
        servsock = new ServerSocket(SOCKET_PORT); // creates servsock with socket port
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
            try {

                sock = servsock.accept(); // accepts a socket connection
                System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);
                System.out.println();

                os = sock.getOutputStream(); // sets Output Stream using the sockets output stream
                is = sock.getInputStream(); // get input stream from socket

                // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                // send file
                File myFile = new File(FILE_TO_SEND); // creates a file using file to send path
                byte[] bytearraySent = new byte[(int) myFile.length()]; // creates a byte array the size of myFile

                try {

                    // reads the contents of FILE_TO_SEND into a BufferedInputStream
                    fis = new FileInputStream(myFile); // creates new FIS from myFile
                    bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis); // creates BIS with the FIS
                    bis.read(bytearraySent, 0, bytearraySent.length); // copies the BIS byte array into the byte array

                    // prints to console filename and size
                    System.out.println("Sending " + FILE_TO_SEND + "(" + bytearraySent.length + " bytes)");
                    System.out.println("byte array from file to send:" + bytearraySent);

                    // copies the byte array into the output stream therefore sending it through the
                    // socket
                    os.write(bytearraySent, 0, bytearraySent.length);
                    os.flush(); // flush/clears the output stream
                } finally {

                    fis.close();
                    bis.close();
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("sendFile complete");
                System.out.println();

                // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                // receive file
                int bytesRead;

                byte[] bytearrayReceived = new byte[FILE_SIZE]; // creates byte aray using file size
                fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED); // creates file from path
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); // creates BOS from FOS
                int current = 0; // equals the two integers for comparisons later
                try {

                    System.out.println(String.format("Bytes available from received file:  %d", is.available()));

                    System.out.println("byte array from file to receive:  " + bytearrayReceived); // debug purposes

                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytearrayReceived)) != -1) {

                        System.out.println("amount of bytes that was read for while:  " + bytesRead);

                        bos.write(bytearrayReceived, 0, bytesRead);
                        System.out.println("bos.write");

                        current += bytesRead;
                        System.out.println("current += bytesRead;");
                    }
                    System.out.println("File " + FILE_TO_RECEIVED + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
                } finally {

                    fos.close();
                    bos.close();
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("receiveFile complete");
                System.out.println();

                // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            } // end of try
            finally {

                // if any streams or sockets are not null, the close them
                if (os != null)
                    os.close();
                if (is != null)
                    is.close();
                if (sock != null)
                    sock.close();
            } // end of finally
        } // end of while
    } // end of try
    finally {

        if (servsock != null)
            servsock.close();
    } // end of finally
}
```

}

public class Client2 {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Socket sock = null; // used in main
    String SERVER = "localhost"; // local host
    int SOCKET_PORT = 12362; // you may change this

    InputStream is = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;

    OutputStream os = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    String FILE_TO_RECEIVED = "SFileReceived.txt";
    String FILE_TO_SEND = "CFileToBeSent.txt";
    int FILE_SIZE = 6022386;

    try {

        sock = new Socket(SERVER, SOCKET_PORT);
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        System.out.println();

        // get input and output from socket
        is = sock.getInputStream(); // get input stream from socket
        os = sock.getOutputStream(); // get output stream from socket

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // receive file
        int bytesRead;

        byte[] bytearrayReceived = new byte[FILE_SIZE]; // creates byte aray using file size
        fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED); // creates file from path
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); // creates BOS from FOS
        int current = 0; // equals the two integers for comparisons later
        try {

            System.out.println(String.format("Bytes available from received file:  %d", is.available()));

            System.out.println("byte array from file to receive:  " + bytearrayReceived); // debug purposes

            while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytearrayReceived)) != -1) {
                System.out.println("amount of bytes that was read for while:  " + bytesRead);

                bos.write(bytearrayReceived, 0, bytesRead);
                System.out.println("bos.write");

                current += bytesRead;
                System.out.println("current += bytesRead;");

            }
            System.out.println("File " + FILE_TO_RECEIVED + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
        } finally {

            fos.close();
            bos.close();
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("receiveFile() complete");
        System.out.println();

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // send file
        File myFile = new File(FILE_TO_SEND); // creates a file using file to send path
        byte[] bytearraySent = new byte[(int) myFile.length()]; // creates a byte array the size of myFile

        try {

            // reads the contents of FILE_TO_SEND into a BufferedInputStream
            fis = new FileInputStream(myFile); // creates new FIS from myFile
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis); // creates BIS with the FIS
            bis.read(bytearraySent, 0, bytearraySent.length); // copies the BIS byte array into the byte array

            // prints to console filename and size
            System.out.println("Sending " + FILE_TO_SEND + "(" + bytearraySent.length + " bytes)");
            System.out.println("byte array from file to send:" + bytearraySent);

            // copies the byte array into the output stream therefore sending it through the
            // socket
            os.write(bytearraySent, 0, bytearraySent.length);
            os.flush(); // flush/clears the output stream
        } finally {

            fis.close();
            bis.close();
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("sendFile() complete");
        System.out.println();

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    } // end of try
    finally {

        if (sock != null)
            sock.close();
        if (os != null)
            os.close();
        if (is != null)
            is.close();
    } // end of finally
}
```

}

Server output:--------------------

Server created.

Waiting for connection...

Accepted connection : Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=51565,localport=12362]

Sending SFileToBeSent.txt(32 bytes)

byte array from file to send:[B@4e25154f

sendFile complete

Bytes available from received file:  0

byte array from file to receive:  [B@70dea4e

Client output--------------------

Connecting...

Bytes available from received file:  32

byte array from file to receive:  [B@4e25154f

amount of bytes that was read for while:  32

bos.write

current += bytesRead

---

I still have the issue with InputStream, and i have found out through debugging that both the server and client get stuck on the while() statement that is in the receive section. For the server, it stops immediately, whereas the client goes through the while loop once then stops when it hits the while statement.

If anyone has any suggestions or solutions, then it would be much appreciated!

Comment: TCP sockets are full-duplex, and so are Java `Sockets` and the streams you get from them. No interference. Many of your variables are static when they should not be static.

Comment: @user207421 I appreciate the help, but I don't fully understand what you mean by some variables should not be static. Does it mean that i should move variables into the methods usesing them if it is only used in a single method?

Comment: in order to isolate the problem, please add print statements. Or you may use a debugger to track the statement at which the program is stopping.

Answer (score 0):

First , your receiveFile method should read input and write output in a loop. 
Second, please close files after done or you may have a resource leak.

public static void receiveFile() throws IOException {

```
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[FILE_SIZE]; // creates byte aray using file size
fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED); // creates file from path
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); // creates BOS from FOS
int current = 0; // equals the two integers for comparisons later

try {
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray)) != -1) {
        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead );
        current += bytesRead;
    }
    bos.flush(); // clears the buffer
    System.out.println("File " + FILE_TO_RECEIVED + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
} finally {
  bos.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Flush before close is redundant.

Comment: I switched the receive method to what you suggested and closed files.  I looked at the code again and narrowed the problem down to the while loop in the receive method. both the Client and Server "freezes" there. would you happen to know what would be the cause of this?